# Approximating a Riemann integrable function with a smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Let $F: [0,1]^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function. 
Let
$$
J(H) =\int_0^1.. \int_0^1 (\int_{[0,1]} H(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n) dt_1)^2 dt_2 ... dt_n. 
$$
Given $\epsilon > 0$ I want to find $G$ a smooth function such that
$$
|J(F) - J(G)| < \varepsilon.
$$
I was wondering how I could start with this. Any comments are appreciated! Thank you!

Edit: My apologies for the confusion! I had mistakenly oversimplified the part of the article I am trying to understand.

Let 
$$
J^{(m)}(H) =\int_0^1.. \int_0^1 (\int_{[0,1]} H(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n) dt_m)^2 dt_1 ... dt_{m-1}  dt_{m+1}...dt_n. 
$$
$$
I(H) = \int_0^1.. \int_0^1   H^2(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n) dt_1 ...dt_n. 
$$

Let 
$$
M = \sup_{F \in S} \frac{\sum_{m=1}^nJ^{(m)} (F)} {I(F)},
$$
where $S$ is the set of all Riemann integrable functions on $[0,1]^n$. 
Let $\delta > 0$ small. Then there exists 
$F_0 \in S$ such that 
$$
\sum_{m=1}^nJ^{(m)} (F_0) > (M- \delta) I(F_0) > 0. 
$$
This I understand. 
But then they claim that since $F_0$ is Riemann integrable, there exists $F_1$ a smooth function such that 
$$
\sum_{m=1}^nJ^{(m)} (F_1) > (M- 2\delta) I(F_1) > 0. 
$$
I was wondering how this follows. I had mistakenly thought that if I could understand what I had asked above then I could deduce this, but I don't think this is the case seeing the comments and answers. Any explanation for this would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I believe you mean $|J(F-G)| < \varepsilon$, (otherwise you can just take $G$ to be a constant function of value $J(F)$, which is only a very rough approximation of $F$).

Comment: Thank you for the comments/answers! I have fixed the question.

Answer (score 1):

As written, is *utterly* trivial. You can take a *constant* (what constant?) $G$.

Comment: Let me fix the question...

Answer (score 1):

If the limits can vary, you can't. Take e.g. the function that is 1 up to $1/2$, 2 afterwards. No smooth function can have such a derivative.